# what is the meaning of 3 in strftime(3),malloc(3) etc

Tags: c, system-calls, manpage

This might be a silly question. but I was wandering a long time searching for this .but couldn't solve. For some functions I've seen (8) also. They are mostly seen on documentations. Could anyone please help.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean

Comment: ahh it helps. thank you.

Comment: Quick command man -a man

Comment: @kkk thanks... It didn't come to my mind earlier. thankz again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The man pages are divided into sections with different topics:

1 User Commands
2 System Calls
3 C Library Functions
4 Devices and Special Files
5 File Formats and Conventions
6 Games et. al.
7 Miscellanea
8 System Administration tools

`man 2 open` will look for `open` in system calls and tell you details about the Linux system call, while `man 3 open` will look for `open` in C Library Functions and tell you about the ANSI or POSIX specification of open.

See the difference here for example:
http://linux.die.net/man/2/open
http://linux.die.net/man/3/open

Comment: thankz. sory I didn't get it clearly. So how do you enter it in the man pages.I mean how to enter it in the commandline "man malloc 3 " some  other thing

Answer (score 6):

Often in the manual `man` you will see numbers after the functions to distinguish which section of the manual the page comes from.

You can view `malloc(3)` by typeing `man 3 malloc` on a unix style terminal with the appropriate man pages installed.

These are not specific to the C language.